# How to resolve a SwiftData PredicateExpressions error

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift-data

I'm trying to save Category objects in SwiftData:

```
@Model
class Category: Decodable, Identifiable {
    var id: Int
    var title: String
}
```

In a viewModel I'm doing this:

```
init(modelContext: ModelContext) {
    self.modelContext = modelContext
    Task {
        categories = await SomeManager.shared.parseCategories() //from json
        for category in categories {
            categoryFetchDescriptor.predicate = #Predicate { item in
                return item.id == category.id
            }
            
            do {
                let existingCategory = try modelContext.fetch(categoryFetchDescriptor)
                
                if existingCategory.first == nil {
                    modelContext.insert(category)
                }
            } catch {
                print("SwiftData Error: \(error)")
            }
        }
        setup()
    }
}
```

When I try to run the app, I get this Xcode error:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'PredicateExpressions.Equal<PredicateExpressions.KeyPath<PredicateExpressions.Variable<Category>, Int>, PredicateExpressions.KeyPath<PredicateExpressions.Value<Category>, Int>>' to closure result type 'any StandardPredicateExpression<Bool>'
```

Why is it having trouble comparing Ints?

Comment: Please show a [mcve] - something I can directly paste into a new project and reproduce the issue. Right now, I have no idea what `category` in `== category.id` is.

Comment: Try creating a local variable for the id, `let categoryId = category.id` before you create the predicate and then use this variable inside the predicate `item.id == categoryId`

Comment: Unrelated but when you get the predicate to work you could use fetchCount instead

Comment: In SwiftUI the `View` struct is the view model and its `.task` for async await not `Task`

Answer (score 2):

This is how I fixed it:

```
let catId = category.id
let categoryPredicate = #Predicate<Category> { $0.id == catId }
```